# Problema con Live Server en WSL: No puedo conectarme al servidor desde mi teléfono

Tags: localhost, wsl, vscode-live-server

Cuando estoy en mi entorno de **Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)** desde VS Code no puedo conectarme al servidor desde mi teléfono a pesar de estar conectado a la misma red wifi y estar ingresando la dirección ip y el puerto.

Cuando trabajo desde mi entorno normal en windows (sin estar en el WSL) la extensión funciona perfectamente y puedo abrir mi proyecto desde mi teléfono sin problemas al conectarme al servidor ingresando la dirección ip y el puerto. Sin embargo, estando en el WSL por alguna razón ya no funciona, y me gustaría solucionarlo que ya suelo trabajar constantemente en mi entorno de WSL.

**Estos son los pasos que realizo para intentar abrir mi proyecto desde mi teléfono:**

1. Estando en mi entorno de WSL con mi proyecto abierto en el VS Code, uso la extensión de Live Server y le doy clic a "Go Live".
2. Con el servidor ya iniciado en el puerto predeterminado 5500, uso la terminal desde mi entorno de WSL para averiguar cuál es la dirección ip de mi pc mediante el comando `ip addr`.
3. Compruebo que la dirección ip es la correcta ingresándola en el navegador de la pc.
4. Y finalmente intento conectarme desde mi teléfono ingresándola en el navegador del mismo estando conectado a la red wifi.

Cuando estoy en mi entorno normal de windows (sin estar en WSL) sigo igualmente los anteriores 4 pasos y **todo funciona perfectamente y puedo conectarme sin problemas a mi proyecto desde mi teléfono**, sin embargo, extrañamente cuando estoy desde mi entorno de WSL a pesar de seguir los mismos cuatro pasos e ingresar la dirección ip junto al puerto, el proyecto no me carga; como si el servidor estuviera apagado.

Comment: Hola Miguel, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edítala, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que sea mejor recibida, gracias.

Comment: Perdón por los inconvenientes . Gracias por el aviso.

Comment: Nada que perdonar, a todos nos lleva un tiempo conocer las normas del mismo.